# Como zipar uma pasta com php

Tags: php

Estou tentando zipar a pasta `img` para jogar na pasta **zipado**, porém não estou tendo sucesso.

Queria saber qual o erro? Pois já vi alguns tutorias e não consigo zipar

```php
    $diretorio = getcwd().'/zipado/'; //para onde vou mandar

    $zip = new ZipArchive(); 

    if($zip->open('nome_arquivo_zip.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) == TRUE){
        $zip->addFile($diretorio.'teste.zip', getcwd().'/img/');
    }
```

Comment: A aplicação está retornando algum erro? Ou o arquivo não está sendo salvo apenas?

Comment: O arquivo não está sendo salvo

Comment: Tenta colocar após esse addFile, o seguinte código: $zip->close();

Comment: Você já viu os parâmetros que o método `addFile` recebe? O primeiro é o *filename* do arquivo a ser adicionado e você está passando o nome do próprio Zip.

Answer (score 0):

O arquivo pode não estar sendo salvo por conta do ZipArchive não estar sendo "fechado" após a adição dos arquivos. Para salvar o arquivo, basta adicionar o seguinte código abaixo do addFile();

```
$diretorio = getcwd().'/zipado/'; //para onde vou mandar

$zip = new ZipArchive(); 

if($zip->open('nome_arquivo_zip.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) == TRUE){
    $zip->addFile(getcwd().'/img/');
    $zip->close();
}
```

O método close() salva o arquivo e faz a alteração com base nos itens adicionados/removidos do Objeto ZipArchive.

Comment: Vinicius nada também